# Big O of computing the sum from 1 to n

Tags: algorithms

Could you help me to solve that how many **digit operations** do you need to compute the sum 1+2+3+···+n? Can you come up a bound in **O-notation** which is as good as possible?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

There is a formula for that. $\sum_{i=1}^ni=n(n-1)/2$. All you need now is a good multiplication algorithm.

You can also take JnxF's suggestion in the comments to speed up your process even more.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that dividing an integer by 2 is done by a right arithmetic (or logical) shift (i.e. swapping cables) in constant time.